# Через какой метод можно обращаться к событиям клавиатуры на маке?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

1.Есть поле из символов

```
. . . . .
. @. . 
. . . . .
```

2. По нажатию на клавишу клавиатуры на Mac нужно двигать символ `@`
3. Всё происходит в консоли Xcode

Как реагировать на события клавиатуры?

Comment: «Всё происходит в консоли Xcode» — эээ, программа будет поставляться клиенту вместе с XCode?

Comment: Это никуда не будет поставляться! Это просто задача!

Answer (score 2):

Любой класс, являющийся наследником NSResponder отвечает на keyDown или keyUp

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter =
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

unsigned short keyCode = [theEvent keyCode];
if([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask && keyCode == 36 /*Cmd+Enter*/)
{
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"cmdEnterKeyPressedNotification"
                                      object:nil];
    return;
}
if(keyCode == 36 /*Enter*/)
{
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"enterKeyPressedNotification"
                                      object:nil];
    return;
}
if(keyCode == 49 /*Space*/)
{
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"spaceKeyPressedNotification"
                                      object:nil];
    return;
}
[super keyDown:theEvent];
```

}